# Standard Deviation Array(My algorithm is wrong)

Tags: java

I am a beginner learning how to program.

```
public static void main()
{
    int array[] = {1,-2,4,-4,9,-6,16,-8,25,-10};
    System.out.print(stdev(array));
}
public static double stdev(int array[])
{
    int stdev = 0;
    int average = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<array.length;i++)
    {
        average = average+array[i];
    }
    average = average/array.length;
    for(int i = 0; i <array.length;i++)
    {
        stdev = stdev +(array[i]- average)*(array[i]- average);
    }
    return Math.sqrt((double) stdev/(array.length));
}
```

}

In my textbook it says that the return value is 11.237, but I got 10.672. Please check my java codes. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

average and stdev should be doubles, not ints.

```
average = average/array.length;
```

Otherwise you end up using int division which returns a truncated number.

---

The difference is that your calculation should use the "Corrected Standard Deviation" as per the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Corrected_sample_standard_deviation). The numerator in the square root should be the length of the array - 1:

```
public static double stdev(int array[]) {
  double sum = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     sum += array[i];
  }
  double average = sum / array.length;

  double sumOfSquares = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     sumOfSquares += (array[i] - average) * (array[i] - average);
  }

  // **** the issue is below -- you need to subtract 1 from array.length ******
  return Math.sqrt(sumOfSquares / (array.length - 1));
}
```

Comment: or `BigDecimal` for even more prescision

Comment: @JigarJoshi: a bit of overkill perhaps.

Comment: ohhh yeeaaa.. i see xD

Comment: @axue2014: Let's see what you've done: Please post any new code to the bottom of your original question by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23796976/edit).

Comment: @axue2014: you need to correct your formula. Please see edit to answer.